# Swift Custom Navigation Bar Item With Observer

Tags: swift, swift2

So I have this custom navigation bar item that I would like to subclass out and use in other `ViewControllers`. The issue is that the Bar Item also has an `observer` that I want to add on `ViewDidAppear` and remove the `observer` on `ViewDidDisappear`. How can I `subclass` the bar item along with the `observer` out. And include it in each of my `ViewControllers` instead of duplicating code?

Current Code:

In each `ViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   if (!observingDefaults) {
      defaults.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: Constants.General.kConnectedToPC, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
      observingDefaults = true
   }

   self.updateConnectionIcon()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if (observingDefaults) {
        defaults.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: Constants.General.kConnectedToPC)
        observingDefaults = false
    }
}
```

My Extension For The Nav Bar Item:

```
extension UIViewController {

func updateConnectionIcon() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

    let isConnected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Constants.General.kConnectedToPC)

    let button = UIButton()

    if isConnected {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BluetoothEnabled")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BluetoothDisabled")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 31)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
}
```

Anyway I can add the top half to the bottom code so I can just call updateConnectionIcon() in each `ViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than putting observer in each viewController, create one BaseClase and keep it there and inherit all class which needs these observer. is that make sense?

Comment: Yes It does. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide small example?